# Assign a value within a new column if a condition is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
Date                   ID        Tweet                         Note         
01/20/2020           4141    The cat is on the table          I bought a table      
01/20/2020           4142    The sky is blue                  Once upon a time 
01/20/2020           53      What a wonderful day             I have no words
```

I would like to select rows containing in Tweet or Note one of the following words:

```
w=["sky", "table"]
```

To do this, I am using the following:

```
    def part_is_in(x, values):
        output = False
        for val in values:
            if val in str(x):
                return True
                break                
        return output


def fun_1(filename):
    w=["sky", "table"]
    filename['Logic'] = filename[['Tweet','Note']].apply(part_is_in, values=w)
    filename['Low_Tweet']=filename['Tweet']
    filename['Low_ Note']=filename['Note']
    lower_cols = [col for col in filename if col not in ['Tweet','Note']]
    filename[lower_cols]= filename[lower_cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower(),axis=1)

# NEW COLUMN
    
    filename['Logic'] = pd.Series(index = filename.index, dtype='object')
    filename['TF'] = pd.Series(index = filename.index, dtype='object')
    
    for index, row in filename.iterrows():
            value = row['ID']

            if any(x in str(value) for x in w):
                filename.at[index,'Logic'] = True
            else:
                filename.at[index,'Logic'] = False
                filename.at[index,'TF'] = False

    for index, row in filename.iterrows():
            value = row['Tweet']

            if any(x in str(value) for x in w):
                filename.at[index,'Logic'] = True
            else:
                filename.at[index,'Logic'] = False
                filename.at[index,'TF'] = False
    
    for index, row in filename.iterrows():
            value = row['Note']

            if any(x in str(value) for x in w):
                filename.at[index,'Logic'] = True
            else:
                filename.at[index,'Logic'] = False
                filename.at[index,'TF'] = False
               
    return(filename)
```

What it should do is finding rows having at least one of the words in the list above (w) and assigning a value:

- if the row contains in Tweet or Note the word, then assign True, else False.

My expected output would be:

```
Date                   ID        Tweet                         Note               Logic     TF
01/20/2020           4141    The cat is on the table          I bought a table     True     False 
01/20/2020           4142    The sky is blue                  Once upon a time     True     False
01/20/2020           53      What a wonderful day             I have no words      False    False
```

Manually checking, I found that some words are not correctly assigned. What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: Please explain what this means `Manually checking, I found that some words are not correctly assigned.` It would help if you added atleast a few rows where the results are incorrect, along with your expectation. I'm guessing that this has to do only with the `Logic` column.

Comment: I think the TF column/Series will always yield 'False' (or at least it will never be 'True').  The only values being assigned to the 'TF' series are 'Fa'se'.

Comment: Yes, it should be always false. I checked the values manually to see if the number of rows found by selecting those including those words match the columns selected manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to pandas as well, so you'll need to take this answer with a grain of salt.  I got the impression from the tutorial if you are iterating through the DataFrame, you are not using pandas as it was intended.

To that end, I'll point this out:

```
df['Logic'] = df['Tweet'].str.contains('table')
df['Logic'] |= df['Tweet'].str.contains('sky')
```

Yields:

```
      Date    ID                    Tweet              Note  Logic 
0  1/20/20  4141  The cat is on the table  I bought a table   True 
1  1/20/20  4142          The sky is blue  Once upon a time   True 
2  1/20/20    53     What a wonderful day   I have no words  False
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand if the keywords are in those specific column then `Logic` is True else `TF` is false and `Logic` is false. I couldn't figure out when `TF` is false and `Logic` is true. So I'm not sure if this helps but

```
pattern = '|'.join(w) 
df['Logic'] = df.Tweet.str.contains(pattern) | df.Note.str.contains(pattern)
```

this code may help you to avoid from `apply`.